# Dynamic SQL using Sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I have a stored procedure which I have to rewrite using `sp_executesql`. I want to use `sp_executesql` instead of `exec` because of performance issue on my SQL Server instance.

Here is my code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_TestSp1] 
      @Type1 VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(2000) = ''
    DECLARE @columnList varchar(1000) = ''
    DECLARE @dynamicSql varchar(1000) = ''

    IF  (@Type1 IS NOT NULL )
    BEGIN
    SET @dynamicSql = @dynamicSql + 'AND tbl1.DTypeID IN ( '+ @Type1+ ' )' 
    END     

SET @columnList = 'SELECT DISTINCT tbl2.ID, Name AS PName '
SET @sqlCommand =  @columnList 
                    + ' FROM tbl1 '
                    + ' INNER JOIN tbl3 ON tbl1.NID= tbl3.NID '
                    + ' INNER JOIN tbl4 ON tbl3.DID = tbl4.DID '
                    + ' WHERE TT=1 AND IsActive=1 AND tbl1.DTypeID IN (1,3,5)' 
                    + @dynamicSql
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```

Comment: exec sp_TestSp1 '0); drop table tbl1 --'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your EXEC (@sqlCommand) statement with the following.

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
```

[TechNet Link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Comment: is it simple as that ? :D